# SSRS Visibility Hide iif All

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Just wondering if it is possible to do the following on SSRS for a textbox visibility (hide), it seems to return an error for me:

```
           =iif(parameters!category.value = "All",True,False)
```

I have a long list of category so therefore is impossible to list them all, is it possible to the above? I keep getting an error with the above-outlined syntax

Answer (score 1):

I assume the category parameter is multi-select with available values fed by a SQL query. You can use the Count property on the parameter to get the number of selected items and compare that to the number of items returned by the SQL query using the `COUNT()` SSRS aggregate function with a scope of the dataset. If the number of selected items matches the number of available values then they must be all selected.

So your code would look like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!category.Count = COUNT(Fields!CategoryName.Value, "CategoryParameterDataSetName"), True, False)
```

In this case the dataset that contains all of your available values is named *CategoryParameterDataSetName* and contains a field named *CategoryName*. Change these values as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But, it hasn't solved it. I get the following error now the visibility.hidden expression for the textbox contains an error: [BC30201] Expression Expected

Comment: did you forget the `=` at the start?

Comment: Nope, I had it there.